# Why does OCaml modify the type of a value on first use when it contains a universal?

Tags: ocaml

Why does OCaml change the type of a value of first use when it contains a universal?  For example, if we define a Church encoding for tuples, we have:

```
# let pair x y z = z x y;;
val pair : 'a -> 'b -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'c = <fun>
# let first p = p (fun x y-> x);;
val first : (('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'c) -> 'c = <fun>
# let second p = p (fun x y -> y);;
val second : (('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'c) -> 'c = <fun>
# let foo = pair 1.2 "bob";;
val foo : (float -> string -> '_a) -> '_a = <fun>
# first foo;;
- : float = 1.2
# foo;;
- : (float -> string -> float) -> float = <fun>
# second foo;;
Error: This expression has type (float -> string -> float) -> float
       but an expression was expected of type
         (float -> string -> string) -> 'a
       Type float is not compatible with type string 
# let foo = pair 1.2 "bob";;
val foo : (float -> string -> '_a) -> '_a = <fun>
# second foo;;
- : string = "bob"
# foo;;
- : (float -> string -> string) -> string = <fun>
# first foo;;
Error: This expression has type (float -> string -> string) -> string
       but an expression was expected of type
         (float -> string -> float) -> 'a
       Type string is not compatible with type float
```

Basically, foo has type `val foo : (float -> string -> '_a) -> '_a = <fun>`, but this changes the first time we project out either the first or second element.  Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This called a weak polymorphic type. Lots of questions were asked and answered about this. Feel free to use SO search facilities or read OCaml FAQ. But in short, this is due to value restriction, that usually comes into play when you have partial application or mutable values. In the former case your can strengthen your type with so called eta-expression (in a layman terms, by substituting partial application with normal function invocation). In the latter case, nothing can be made.

Comment: For those interested, I found the relevant FAQ entry here: http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/faq/core.en.html#eta-expansion

Answer (score 1):

As @ivg says, this is the value restriction. Here is how things work if you use eta expansion:

```
# let pair x y z = z x y;;
val pair : 'a -> 'b -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'c = <fun>
# let first p = p (fun x y -> x);;
val first : (('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'c) -> 'c = <fun>
# let second p = p (fun x y -> y);;
val second : (('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'c) -> 'c = <fun>
# let foo x = pair 1.2 "bob" x;;
val foo : (float -> string -> 'a) -> 'a = <fun>
# first foo;;
- : float = 1.2
# second foo;;
- : string = "bob"
```